# 17.10: Bluetooth crashes and can't be turned back on. How to restart?

Tags: sound, 17.10, bluetooth

With laptop Lenovo T540p and Bluetooth headset CEL-TEC F5A,

While using the headset, sometimes Bluetooth crashes (turns off, the icon on the notification area disappears) and can't be turned on.

It works again after restarting the whole system.

**How can I restart just the Bluetooth?**

This is what journalctl says when I click the ON/OFF switch in settings:

```
18:49:58 t540 gnome-control-c[19234]: Failed to register object: 
  An object is already exported for the interface org.bluez.Agent1 at /org/bluez/agent/gnome
18:49:58 t540 indicator-bluetooth-service[2419]: Agent unregistration failed: 
  GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.DoesNotExist: Does Not Exist 'g-io-error-quark'
```

This seems to have no effect: `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

```
$ rfkill list 
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
9: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one more minute of experimenting gave me the result:

```
sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sleep 1 && \
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I had the `Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Blocked` problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`